# Gevent Pywsgi Server - Multiprocessing?

Tags: python, webserver, wsgi, gevent, greenlets

The following code (taken from here: https://bitbucket.org/denis/gevent/src/6c710e8ae58b/examples/wsgiserver_ssl.py) implements an extremely fast greenlet powered wsgi webserver:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
"""Secure WSGI server example based on gevent.pywsgi"""

from gevent import pywsgi


def hello_world(env, start_response):
    if env['PATH_INFO'] == '/':
        start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html')])
        return ["<b>hello world</b>"]
    else:
        start_response('404 Not Found', [('Content-Type', 'text/html')])
        return ['<h1>Not Found</h1>']

print 'Serving on https://127.0.0.1:8443'
server = pywsgi.WSGIServer(('0.0.0.0', 8443), hello_world, keyfile='server.key', certfile='server.crt')
# to start the server asynchronously, call server.start()
# we use blocking serve_forever() here because we have no other jobs
server.serve_forever()
```

However, this only runs on one core. How would you modify this to take advantage of multiple processes? Not looking for an answer that involves gunicorn, looking for something simpler.

**HINT**

Here is a code sample using gevent and multiprocessing, but I still can't figure out how to make this work with WSGI (taken from https://gist.github.com/1169975):

```
import sys
from gevent import server
from gevent.baseserver import _tcp_listener
from gevent.monkey import patch_all; patch_all()
from multiprocessing import Process, current_process, cpu_count


def note(format, *args):
    sys.stderr.write('[%s]\t%s\n' % (current_process().name, format%args))

def echo(socket, address):
    print 'New connection from %s:%s' % address
    fileobj = socket.makefile()
    fileobj.write('Welcome to the echo server! Type quit to exit.\r\n')
    fileobj.write('In %s\r\n' % current_process().name)
    fileobj.flush()
    while True:
        line = fileobj.readline()
        if not line:
            print "client disconnected"
            break
        if line.strip().lower() == 'quit':
            print "client quit"
            break
        fileobj.write(current_process().name + '\t' + line)
        fileobj.flush()
        print "echoed", repr(line)

listener = _tcp_listener(('127.0.0.1', 8001))

def serve_forever(listener):
    note('starting server')
    server.StreamServer(listener, echo).serve_forever()

number_of_processes = 5
print 'Starting %s processes' % number_of_processes
for i in range(number_of_processes):
    Process(target=serve_forever, args=(listener,)).start()

serve_forever(listener)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So why not to make this in the same way?
https://gist.github.com/1217855

```
import sys
from gevent import server
from gevent.baseserver import _tcp_listener
from gevent import pywsgi
from gevent.monkey import patch_all; patch_all()
from multiprocessing import Process, current_process, cpu_count

def hello_world(env, start_response):
    if env['PATH_INFO'] == '/':
        start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html')])
        return ["<b>hello world</b>"]
    else:
        start_response('404 Not Found', [('Content-Type', 'text/html')])
        return ['<h1>Not Found</h1>']

listener = _tcp_listener(('127.0.0.1', 8001))

def serve_forever(listener):
    pywsgi.WSGIServer(listener, hello_world).serve_forever()

number_of_processes = 5
print 'Starting %s processes' % number_of_processes
for i in range(number_of_processes):
    Process(target=serve_forever, args=(listener,)).start()

serve_forever(listener)
```

Comment: But you must understand that 6 ports beter then 1 and faster.So 6 processes with nginx balancing on 6 ports will work better then this.

Comment: You're still creating a single port bottleneck on nginix if you do that.

Comment: This is true, but anyway you will be using reverse-proxy for you python server(for security reason) so why do not use also upstream? Beter to use one to many then one-one-many.

Comment: What type of security problems is this server vulnerable to? It seems to have better protection against DoS attacks and other memory hogging attacks. Wouldn't using a proxy in front remove the advantage of using greenlets?

Comment: Without revers-proxy your application can do something unexpected, or just kill DB, or something. But with revers proxy under attack will be only proxy. Also with reverse proxy you can use HTTPS and this is much better then use them on application side.

Comment: No reverse-proxy will not hurt your perfomace(offcourse if you use nginx or HAProxy)

Answer (score 0):

There is also a utility that works with gevent for this problem called GIPC.

https://gehrcke.de/gipc/

The advantage is that you can pass objects back and forth from the processes and communicate.  Just a thought.